# Where is the spaceship operator useful?

Tags: php

I understand how the operator works.

It compresses this:

```
if ($a > $b) {
    return 1;
} else if ($a < b) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

into this

```
$a <=> $b
```

But where and how will I use it?

The only place this is somewhat useful is on the callback of `usort`. Except there, to use the returned value I still have to use `switch` and that defeats the purpose.

```
switch ($a <=> $b) {
    case -1: //code
    case 0:  //code
    case 1:  //code
}
```

Update: My question is not how to use it or how it works. I am asking where this is useful.

Comment: Even if you *just* use it for `usort`, isn't that pretty good already? That's an obvious use case. I'm sure you'll discover other potential use cases over time. You can have this kind of discussion about pretty much any keyword/operator: there are always other ways to write the same thing.

Comment: The [main purpose](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator#usefulness) of this operator introduced on PHP 7 is to simplify the writing of callback comparison functions for [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and similar.

Comment: "How to use it" and "where is it useful" are virtually the same question! You use it when you want to compare two values and need a return value of <0, 0 or >0. Beyond this it's purely opinion based in which specific code situations you can use this to solve a problem.

Comment: Let me rephrase: where would I need this operator except in the usort function? Give me an example of where you used it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for polling for random examples. – No, I cannot currently think of an example other than `usort` off the top of my head. But I'll keep this in the back of my mind should I ever encounter a situation where it *is* useful.